# Vertical center each line in multi line edittext

Tags: android, android-edittext

I have a multiline edittext with maxLines as 1. When the input exceeds more than one line, the previous lines entered shift by few pixels to top as shown in image 1 below. 
How can i center vertical each line in edittext?

[image: Image 1]

[image: Image 2]

```
<EditText android:id="@+id/et"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="30dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
    android:paddingStart="10dp"
    android:paddingEnd="10dp"
    android:maxLines="1"
    android:inputType="textMultiLine|textNoSuggestions"/>
```

Comment: I think you're looking for `android:gravity="centerVertical"`

Comment: That did not center vertical each line. When i scroll up..it is looking like image 1 only.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out:

You've set `android:layout_height="30dp"` and depending on the user phone's font size or your own app's it will show just part of it or have extra room like you had in your first picture:

change the `EditText` to:

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/et"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
    android:paddingStart="10dp"
    android:paddingEnd="10dp"
    android:maxLines="1"
    android:inputType="textMultiLine|textNoSuggestions"
    />
```

I've tested it and worked fine, but let me know if it's not working for you.

Comment: Thanks for your response. But even after changing to wrap content, i could see some part of next line :/

Comment: @DevMarc, retry with removing the `textMultiLine` flag from `inputType`.

Comment: Okay. That removed the multiline feature.